# C++ Builder XE: Installing a component

Tags: include, components, c++builder

I'm having some troubles installing components for the C++ Builder XE: when I try to install a the component, the following error appears:

"The project already contains a form or module named somename"

I once installed the wrong version of this component and removed it afterwards. Since then, I'm not able to install it again. I searched the options of the C++Builder XE for include and library paths as well as the registry and removed all entries i could find that pointed to the component. Unfortunately, I could not get rid of the above error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out how to deal with the error. When using the wizard, the following error pops up :

```
"The project already contains a form or module named somename"
```

I removed the .dcu file from the project (it's the components icon) and added the .pas file manually. The .dcu file is than added again and manually building and installing the component then works!

The same error message occurs if the package name is the same as the name of the .pas file.

@Rudy: I guess this is a bug in the wizard?

Answer (score 2):

In which package did you install the wrong version of the component? The package probably still contains the component and that is why you can't install the proper version. Go to `Component` -> `Install packages...` and find the package and the components it has. Now look if the component is still in there.

If it is, uninstall the package, open the package source (the .dpk) and remove the component from the package, using the Project Manager. Now install the package again. Check in the dialog I mentioned above, and see if the component is gone.

If it is gone, you can install the new one.

Comment: I searched all the installed packages for my component, but couldn't find it!

Comment: Hmmm... then it gets complicated. I'll have to check at home (I'm at work now, and no C++Builder here). Hang on...

Comment: Thanks for the effort! What I tried so far: I removed the C++ Builder XE installation and tried to remove all files from that installation (in program files, my documents, shared program files, application data). I also deleted everything in the registy that said embarcadero...I installed the IDE again -> same problem!
Could it be a problem that I still have a BCB 5 installation, where on older version of the same component is installed, causes the problem?

Comment: I don't think that BCB5 is the problem, even if it has an older version. But it could be that the package .cbproj file for your XE package somehow adds the path that contains the old version of the component to its path. .cbproj files are simple XML. Search the package(s) you installed yourself for a reference to such a directory.

Comment: Rudy, 
unfortunately, I can't even find out in which package it could be. Today I - in my desperation - installed the C++ Builder XE on a different machine and tried to install the component - same error again. Funnily, other components do work without any problems.

Comment: If it doesn't even work in a fresh install, something is wrong or you are using a component name that is the same as an existing component or class. What it is, is hard to tell from here.

Comment: FWIW, how do you install the component? Are you using the Component -> Install Component wizard (I wrote that wizard <g>), or are you doing it manually, i.e. create a new package, add the component to it and install that? It could be a bug in the wizard...

Comment: Hey, I'm using the Component -> Install Component wizard. The component is called "XPrinter". I could send you the source, if you want to give it a try.

Comment: Yes, just do so. Use the email address at the bottom of http://www.rvelthuis.de/programs/compinstall.html.

Comment: I think I found it. Will try to install it in C++Builder XE.

Comment: OK, I tried to install it. I do not get the error message you get, so there must be another instance of the file, somewhere on your system. There are a lot of warnings and a few error messages, as the file is not updated for Unicode (since Delphi/C++Builder 2009). I will correct the errors and see what happens.

Comment: After I updated the component for Unicode, I had no problems installing it. I had no errors about XPrinter.pas being in my project already. Please check the project file for the project for any references to it, and use Everything (www.voidtools.com) to see if you may have multiple copies of it, etc. Since I can't reproduce the error, I don't know what else could be causing it.

Comment: Rudy, could you please send me your updated XPrinter component? I almost got it up and running now by manually installing it without the usage of the wizard. Thanks!

Comment: @mort: Wiil do, later this day. Must go now.